# how to pytest parametrize whole test flow

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test flow of test cases like this

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("args", [1, 2])
class TestClass:
    def test_first(self, args):
        print(args)

    def test_second(self, args):
        print(args)
```

the point is that i want to execute them in order test_first test_second and then again test_first, test_second, but instead parametrize is executing them each twice.

Comment: It's bad practice to require a certain test run order in the first place...

Comment: @AKX i have an user flow to test, and i am just separating the functions into test cases, i know its a bad practice, but i dont know a better solution, any suggestions?

Comment: Separate them into regular functions and run them sequentially in a single test.

Comment: @AKX the point is that its a very long user flow, and also some steps may fail but it wont stop the whole user flow, meaning i kinda need a report to visualize the final result of the "test cases" and doing that with one function would be impossible, as it displays only the result of a whole flow.

Comment: When you want to have a end2end test with a test flow and such, consider [`robot`](https://robotframework.org/), [`FitNesse`](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AcceptanceTests), [`RSpec`](https://rspec.info/), or similar. 
If you want to include that into your UnitTest Suite consider a separate folder (to be run seperately) and organize each test case in a single test with multiple steps (e.g. sub-methods).

Comment: Well, then you'll need something like https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/ . . .